# Get Google Sheets script to repeat the same steps automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to scripting.

I have a set of numbers in column X that I would like to (one at a time) have copied into cell T1, which will then return a result on Q11. I then want it to copy the result in Q11 and paste it on column Y next to the number originally copied from X

I have managed to start the below 2 different options, how do I get it to keep repeating the steps for every row of column X and Y?

**Option 1:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('T1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=X1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Y1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

**Option 2:**

```
function myFunction2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('T1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('X1').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Y1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Q11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do that `one at a time` ? do you want to see the changes hapenning actively ? or the end result is the goal?

Comment: @Marios: I don't need to see the changes happening, they just need to be copied one by one because the formula calls/points to several other cells to give the result on Q11. Tks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Q11` is a simple function that only uses `T1` as its input, it would be better to stick to formulas. You can probably use `ARRAYFORMULA` ([see docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)) in the first cell to apply it to the entire column (so it’s automatically applied to the entire column).

If that cannot be done or what you want is to practice using Google Apps Script, you can use a simple loop together with `getValue` and `setValue` to achieve it:

```js
function computeData() {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 const inputRange = sheet.getRange('T1')
 const resultRange = sheet.getRange('Q11')
 
 for (let i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
   const xRange = sheet.getRange(`X${i}`)
   const yRange = sheet.getRange(`Y${i}`)
 
   const x = xRange.getValue()
   inputRange.setValue(x)
 
   const result = resultRange.getValue()
   yRange.setValue(result)
 }
}
```

It’s worth noting that this script is slow and if you can make the algorithm in the script, it’s better to use `getValues` of all the values in the column, compute them all and finally do `setValues` to the other column.

Note: The example script requires the V8 runtime (currently the default one). If the Apps Script project is old, make sure that it’s properly set up.

### References

- [ARRAYFORMULA (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [SpreadsheetApp getActiveSheet() (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
- [Sheet getRange(a1Notation) (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))
- [Range getValue() (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Range setValue(value) (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [Range getValues() (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range setValues(values) (Apps Script Reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [JavaScript For Loop (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: @Marios As I understand the question, he only needs to copy every `X` to `T1` which updates the result in `Q11`. Either way, it's easy to change from one to the other. Also, I was writing this answer while you posted yours, so I didn't realize that until I already posted it :)

Comment: @Martí thank you so much! I ended up using yours as it seems to run better for me. It seems however like there is a time limit of how long the script can run for. Is there a way to get it to check the first free cell on Y so that when I start it again it continues from where it stopped?

Comment: @SamT It depends on what you are doing in the spreadsheets. Like I said in my answer, your best bet is either using only formulas or computing everything in Google Apps Script. The reason is that interfacing with the spreadsheet itself is really slow. It is possible to make batches but it's more a hack than a solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

I am confident that your approach can be further optimized. The calculation of `Q11` can be somehow changed to incorporate the values of all relevant rows/columns and therefore use single `getRange` and `getValue/setValue` calls.

However, I will respect your logic since I can't see your file, but keep in mind that the following approach is not generally recommended and it is going to be slow for large number of data.

- The first step is to iterate over the rows of your sheet (`"Sheet1"` - changed that to the name of your sheet) until the last row with content. Make sure that matches the last row of content of column `X`.

For every row:

- set the value of `T` with the value of `X`.
- set the value of `Y` with the value of `Q11`.

It is a good idea to use [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) to apply all the pending changes as this script is going to iteratively interact with the sheet.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction(){
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1') // change it to the name of your sheet
  const lrow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  [...Array(lrow)].forEach((_,i)=>{                          
       sheet.getRange(`T${i+1}`).setValue(sheet.getRange(`X${i+1}`).getValue());
       sheet.getRange(`Y${i+1}`).setValue(sheet.getRange('Q11').getValue()); 
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  });
}
```